# lastsave command for previously saved key

Tags: redis

I need to see when the key is saved lastly.
But its returning an error for the command

```
redis-cli lastsave "mykey"  

 (error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'lastsave' command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs - [`LASTSAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/lastsave) accepts 0 arguments and reports the last time that the **entire** database was persisted.